# Как сделать так, чтобы элементы интерфейса отображались в круге?

Tags: java, android, android-ui

Учу android. Хочу использовать в своем приложении такой графический вид, как ниже на изображении. Долго гуглил, но ничего не нашел (может быть, не так или не там искал).

Вопрос: как `ImageButton` и `TextView` можно вписать в круг? Если круг - это отдельный элемент графического интерфейса, то как можно элементы наложить друг на друга?

[image: ui-component]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Элементы могут накладываться друг на друга если родительский компонент `view group` не унаследован от `LinearLayout`, т.е. подойдут `FrameLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, `CoordinatorLayout`, `ConstraintLayout`.

А нарисовать круг на фоне можно через Drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/red"/>
    <size
        android:width="30dp"
        android:height="30dp"/>
</shape>
```

А после установить у родительского компонента параметр `android:src="@drawable/название_вашего_файла_с_кругом"`

Очень доходчиво объясняют в уроках [здесь](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/377-urok-162-grafika-drawable-shape-gradient.html)

Comment: лучше установить бэкграунд контейнеру, который содержит виджеты. а не форвард-изображение какому то компоненту. кем бы он ни был.

Comment: Бэкграунд, может быть растянут, так что это не лучшая идея

Comment: Спасибо огромное, буду пробовать!

Comment: @Александр не могли бы принять ответ, если он помог вам. Тут принято так: ["Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?"](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)